# Having trouble passing _id parameter in Login.controller

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm using angular-fullstack-generator.

I'm having trouble with passing _id parameter to some function.
What I'm trying to achieve is after I created a user I want to create another Data in schema referencing to user's id

therefore here is my code

```
'use strict';

class SignupVendorController {
  //end-non-standard

  constructor(Auth, $state, $http) {
      this.Auth = Auth;
      this.$state = $state;
      this.$http = $http;
      this.submitted = false;
    }
    //start-non-standard


  register(form) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (form.$valid) {
      this.Auth.createUser({
          firstName: this.user.firstName,
          lastName: this.user.lastName,
          email: this.user.email,
          password: this.user.password,
          role: 'vendor'
        })
        .then( Auth => {

          this.vendor = Auth.getCurrentUser;
          this.createVendor(this.vendor._id);
          console.log('user is ' + this.vendor.firstName);
          console.log('vendor created');
          // Account created, redirect to home
          this.$state.go('main');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          err = err.data;
          this.errors = {};

          // Update validity of form fields that match the mongoose errors
          angular.forEach(err.errors, (error, field) => {
            form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
            this.errors[field] = error.message;
          });
        });
    }
  }


  createVendor(id) {

          var vendor = {
            category: ['publishing'],
            _owner: id
          }

          this.$http.post('/api/vendors', vendor);

  }

}

angular.module('aApp')
  .controller('SignupVendorController', SignupVendorController);
```

I've tried several syntax modification but it all just got undefined variable on this.vendor.

like this, for instance

```
var vendor = Auth.getCurrentUser;
console.log('the user is ' + vendor.firstName);
```

the code cannot read either _id or firstName.
Any kind of help would be very appreciated.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?:

```
this.vendor = Auth.getCurrentUser();
console.log('the user_id is ' + this.vendor._id);
```

In my App, that's working.